# Powershell SMO Can't Connect

Tags: sql, powershell, smo

I'm having an issue connecting to a SQL Server using SMO when using a ServerConnection. For the last few months this has been working, but now failing. Here is a snippet of the script:

```
        $svrname = "Server"

        #Establish Server connection
        Write-ColorOutput "Establishing SQL Server Connection to $svrName" "White"
        $mysvrConn = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection
        $mysvrConn.ServerInstance=$svrName
        $mysvrConn.LoginSecure = $false
        $mysvrConn.Login = "Admin"
        $mysvrConn.Password = "Password"

        $svr = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server' $mysvrConn
```

However, the following works.

```
$svrname = "Server"
$svr = new-object ('Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO.Server') $svrname
```

And the assemblies:

```
        Write-ColorOutput "Loading assemblies" "White"
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SQLServer.Smo") | out-null
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | out-null
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | out-null
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have permission issues with your SQL login. You are either using the wrong password, or the login does not have the proper creds.

Embarrassingly, when I had this issue, it turned out to be that I had entered the login password incorrectly.

I had expected a specific error stating the login failed. Instead it was the more generic: `Failed to connect to server localhost.`, which threw me off.

Like you, I ran a test with the `$LoginSecure = $True` which worked, telling me that the connection to the server was fine. Only then did I spot my typo and was on my way to SMO bliss.